# CSV with too few fields in one line does not cause an error in Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

It looks like that with `pandas` I can read CSV files without errors or warnings even if one of the lines have to less fields.

The example CSV file has tree columsn but the second row as a missing field.

```
A;B;C
D;E
F;G;H
```

Example:

```
import pandas
import io

csv = io.StringIO('A;B;C\nD;E\nF;G;H')

df = pandas.read_csv(csv, encoding='utf-8', sep=';',
                     header=None,
                     error_bad_lines=True,
                     warn_bad_lines=True)

print(df)
```

Look at the second row of the result. The last field is empty. No warning.

```
   0  1    2
0  A  B    C
1  D  E  NaN
2  F  G    H
```

From the documentation I know that pandas would inform me, if there are to many fields.

I want a warning or an error. How can I catch such situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that `pandas` is not able to detect error's like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code to check if any values in the dataframe are `NaN`:

```py
df.isna().values.any()
```

if it returns True, then you have a blank, and do your new code to handle blanks. If it is false, you are good to rock and roll.

Comment: But I expect `NaN` in some fields. So this is not an indicator here.

Comment: When do you expect an `NaN` other than when the csv is blank? Are there some blanks in the CSV that are acceptable and others that aren't?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Of course there are blank values in some obervations/cases/row.