# ParserError in read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read 100 CSVs and collate data from all into a single CSV.
I made use of :

```
all_files = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files :
   all_files = all_files.append(pd.read_csv(file,encoding= 'unicode_escape')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

where files = list of filepaths of 100 CSVs

Now each CSV may have different number of columns. single CSV, each row may have different no. of colums too.
I want to match the column headers names, put the data from all the CSVs in the correct column, and keep on adding new columns to my final DF on the go.

The above code works fine for 30-40 CSVs and then breaks and gives the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 78, saw 17
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The error is telling you that there is a malformed line in your file

Comment: @Mortz Hi Mortz, thank you for responding. Yes, I got that. But how do I overcome this challenge? These CSV's have a lot of inconsistency, blank spaces, null values, extra trailing spaces. so on and so forth.

Comment: CSV format is consistent, if you have an inconsistent CSV then it's not a CSV format anymore, there read_csv cannot be used out of the box.

Comment: Beware of `all_files = all_files.append...` in your for loop. The `append` method updates the list in place and returns `None`

Comment: I would recommend that you break up your MWE into some more atomic lines. Currently there happens to much things at once in your 3rd line. And about your "inconsistent" CSV files. I would recommand to open a new question for this and show us some examples to find a solution. It seems that your files need to be fixed one step before you do `read_csv()`. You can use my own [`buhtzology.read_and_validate_csv()`](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/buhtzology/src/commit/cffa2306eb3c0c6f3829fec88496c80c69baaea0/bandas.py#L265).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to read variable length csv files -

First, you can specify the column names beforehand. If you are not sure of the number of columns, you can give a reasonably large number of columns

`df = pd.read_csv(filename.csv, header=None, names=list(range(10)))`

The other option is to read the entire file into a single column using a different delimiter - and then split on commas

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename.csv, header=None, sep='\t')
df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `pd.read_csv()` does not thrown an error if there are less then 10 fields in it. If fields are missing they are just filled up with `NA`. A robust solution is to check via `split()` as you mentioned.

Comment: @buhtz Are you sure about the 10 field limit? For instance, `df_str = '\n1,2\n1,2,3\n1,2\n1,2,3,4\n'` and `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str), header=None, engine='python')` gives me an error, even though there are fewer than 5 fields.

Comment: You are right and me, too! ;) In your case the error is there because of the order of your number of fields. This won't give you an error (pandas 1.3.0): `'\n1,2,3,4\n1,2\n1,2,3\n1,2\n'`. Don't trust `pandas` or `csv` here and always check yourself via line by line parsing using something like `len(line.split(sep))`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67775180/4865723

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to read all CSV files into a single Dataframe. When the first file is read number of columns for the DataFrame are decided and then it results in error when a different number of columns are fed. If you really want to concat them you should read them all in python, adjust their coulmns and then concat them

Comment: but doesn't read_csv() creates new column as and when it encounters it ?

Comment: pd.append(..) appends rows at the end of DataFrame. Since there are different columns in every CSV file and you didn't define the number of columns beforehand that is why you are facing this issue. I think the number of columns for DatafFame are decided through the first CSV file and then it expects many features at most. I think you should try @mortz that might work